# Programmatically create a user in Cognito with email and password (permanent password)

Tags: java, authentication, amazon-cognito

I currently have some code that creates a new user with temporary password. I get an email with a temporary password to my account, but instead **I want to get a verification code.** to confirm my email.

here is the code:

```
  public static void registerUser(String email) {
    String userPoolId = "eu-central-1_xxx";
    AWSCognitoIdentityProvider cognitoClient = setUpCognitoClient();
    
    String password = "123456789";
    
    try {
      AdminCreateUserRequest userRequest =
              new AdminCreateUserRequest().withUserPoolId(userPoolId).withUsername(email);
      
      cognitoClient.adminCreateUser(userRequest);
      
      AdminSetUserPasswordRequest adminSetUserPasswordRequest =
              new AdminSetUserPasswordRequest().withUsername(email)
                      .withUserPoolId(userPoolId).withPassword(password).withPermanent(true);
      
      cognitoClient.adminSetUserPassword(adminSetUserPasswordRequest);
    } catch (AWSCognitoIdentityProviderException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getErrorMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    
  }
```

Seems like `.withPermanent(true)` doesn't work.

Also currently I am creating a user with one call and setting the password (`AdminSetUserPasswordRequest()`) with another. Is there a simpler way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised how long it took me to actually find a solution to something quite trivial as creating a user without a temporary password.

```
public static void signUpUser(String email, String password) {
    AWSCognitoIdentityProvider cognitoClient = setUpCognitoClient();
    try {
      SignUpRequest signUpRequest = new SignUpRequest().withUsername(email).withPassword(password).withClientId("xxx");
      cognitoClient.signUp(signUpRequest);
    } catch (AWSCognitoIdentityProviderException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getErrorMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
 }
```

So the difference is stead instead of `.adminCreateUser` I'm using `.signUp`.

In this case you will need your clientId (which is not your pool id!) - `.withClientId("xxx")`.

Tip: switch to the old view of Cognito console to find the client id faster - if will be under `App Clients` tab on the left side menu.

After sign up the user will be not confirmed and not verified and will receive an email with the code to verify email (not temporary password).

btw, my verification email landed in spam - so look there if you got no email.

Comment: Somewhat obvious, but this approach only works if the user pool allows users to sign themselves up. For those which require admins to add users, you will have to use `admin_create_user`.